# How to add_column for table with composite type via DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, dbix-class, composite-types

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-DECLARING

> Whenever you create a table, a composite type is also automatically created, with the same name as the table

So if such composite type is returned by database server (I am using PostgreSQL).
How should I declare my column?

```perl
package App::Schema::Result::Example;

use utf8;
use Modern::Perl;
use parent 'App::Schema::Result';



my $X =  __PACKAGE__;
$X->table_class('DBIx::Class::ResultSource::View');

$X->table('example');
$X->result_source_instance->is_virtual(1);
$X->result_source_instance->view_definition( <<'SQL' );
  select t from my_table t; -- NOTICE: I return row as composite type
SQL

$X->add_columns(
    t => {
        data_type => '????',
    },
);
```

If I for `my_table` already have `App::Schema::Result::Table`, can I just write: `data_type => my_table` or `data_type => App::Schema::Result::Table`?

In case if I can not. How to explain `DBIx::Class` how to extract data from `t` column?

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread how to accomplish this: https://groups.google.com/g/perl.dbd.pg/c/roY9y-Tq198?pli=1

So we have tow ways:

1. Use [PGObject](https://metacpan.org/pod/PGObject) perl module
2. Use [`InflateColumn`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::InflateColumn) functionality